# Display different Field Label on Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I created a VF page with a few checkboxes:

checkbox_1__c named 'Check1'

checkbox_2__c named 'Check2'

I want to display **different** field labels on this specific page, such as 'Access Enabled' or 'Access Denied' instead of 'Check1' and 'Check2'.

Can someone explain if this is possible?

Comment: Where did you actually giving name for checkboxes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a label to your CheckBox:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!YourcheckBox__c}" label="Whatever"/>
```

That way you can use any label for your checkbox.

Comment: Ah I didn't think of that, good one!